# Bootstrap PHP Header

Tags: php

I wanted to use a PHP include in my website so making new pages would go very easily but I have got one problem. I also want to include my Navigation in this header.php but my problem is, I have an active class on the active page, so I wanted to know how I can do this using PHP. This is what I have I have now in my header.php but I can't figure it out.

```
<?php
function pageName( $name="" ){

print "
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-gb" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Minecraft Hosting, Minecraft, Hosting, VoxelHost, VoxelHost, Cheap, Reliable, Great Support, Great, Support, Europe, Best Minecraft Host, Best, Minecraft, Host" />
    <meta name="description" content="Voxel Host delivers Cheap and Reliable Hosting Solutions for your daily needs." />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="https://www.voxelhost.com/img/icon.png" />
    <title>Voxel Host - Cheap And Reliable Hosting Solutions</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.voxelhost.com/css/bootstrap.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.voxelhost.com/css/voxelhost.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.voxelhost.com/css/nivo-slider.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.voxelhost.com/css/default.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.voxelhost.com/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.voxelhost.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.voxelhost.com/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.voxelhost.com/js/jquery.slider.nivo.js"></script>
    <!--Start of Zopim Live Chat Script-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.$zopim||(function(d,s){var z=$zopim=function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s=
        d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set.
        _.push(o)};z._=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute('charset','utf-8');
        $.src='//cdn.zopim.com/?bIkq1WcfGahuJo4awX9QoDtEdvXXAClp';z.t=+new Date;$.
        type='text/javascript';e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)})(document,'script');
    </script>
    <!--End of Zopim Live Chat Script-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-35044907-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'voxelhost.com']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
          var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
          ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="alertbar inactive"></div>
    <div class="infobar">We are starting the 20th of October! See you soon!</div>
    <div class="succesbar inactive"></div>
    <div id="topbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.voxelhost.com/billing/supporttickets.php">Support Ticket</a></li>
            <li><a href="mailto:info@voxelhost.com">Email</a></li>
            <li><a href="skype:martijnriemers?chat">Skype</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="logo">
        <div class="align">
            <div class="left" style="width: 500px;">
                <a href="#"><img src="https://www.voxelhost.com/img/logo.png" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar" id="navbarhomepage">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="https://www.voxelhost.com/"><i class="icon-home"></i> &nbsp;Home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="icon-star"></i> &nbsp;Services</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="https://www.voxelhost.com/minecraft/standard">Standard Minecraft Servers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://www.voxelhost.com/minecraft/premium">Premium Minecraft Servers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://www.voxelhost.com/minecraft_reseller">Minecraft Reseller</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://www.voxelhost.com/comingsoon">VPS Hosting</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://www.voxelhost.com/comingsoon">Dedicated Servers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://www.voxelhost.com/comingsoon">Web Hosting</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.voxelhost.com/status"><i class="icon-ok-sign"></i> &nbsp;Server Status</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.voxelhost.com/billing/cart"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> &nbsp;Order Now</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.voxelhost.com/billing/"><i class="icon-user"></i> &nbsp;Client Area</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="icon-dashboard"></i> &nbsp;Control Panels</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="https://mcpanel.voxelhost.com/">Minecraft Servers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://mintpanel.voxelhost.com/">Game Servers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://cpanel.voxelhost.com/">Webhosting</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">" ;

}
?>
```

And this is what I have in my index.php etc.

```
<?php
include( "header.php" );
pageName( "Home" );
?>
```

Many thanks for reading this and maybe helping me out!

Comment: Your talking about the navigation CSS `class="active` dynamic selection based on which page is selected?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That was my question.

Answer (score 3):

Your quotes are causing problems.

To dump a large string, try using HEREDOC:

```
print <<<EOT
<html lang="en">
   ..........
EOT;
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I use php to change the active class then? I found this, https://forums.totalchoicehosting.com/index.php?showtopic=23306, is this something I should use?

Comment: But if I update the header, I have to update all my 30 pages wich would take a lot of time. If I could use one header.php and have a code that manages the "Active" class on my Navigation it will save a lot of time.

Comment: You could, as @LawrenceCherone said, break out of PHP, dump out most of the HTML, then just hop back into PHP to output the variables. In PHP 5.4 (of if you have Short Tags on in earlier versions) you can just write `<?=$varname?>` to output a variable.

Comment: I think I don't understand it anymore. But I guess I'll leave out my Navigation from the header.php then if it is not possible.

Comment: Giving up won't get you anywhere.

Comment: Because the only thing I want is that the code changes my Nav classes, so that when I'm on the home page, the home tab gets the class active.